# Dropwizard: Using migrations for a cloud based application

Tags: java, rest, cloud, liquibase, dropwizard

We are having an application i.e. exposing RESTful web services and we are targeting this application to be deployed in cloud. We need to one time setup a database schema for the application on some database instance in the cloud.
Can someone tell me if it is a good approach to use migrations with liquibase for the one time database schema setup. We will be using alter scripts in case some DDL modification needed in future releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone stop me if I'm wrong, but the fact you application will be deplyed on the cloud only mean it will be on a virtual server hosted by an extern compagnie, wich in the case of your question don't chance anything.

So the question is "is the database versionning system Liquibase on a database with an aimed stable shema worth it".

In absolute it could be considered overkill, and a lot of big companies still manage database schema evolution with bare sql scripts. You could simply export the final built script of your developpement database and go with it.

But since you know Liquibase, the overhead is pretty cheap, and the comfort of using if you happen to have to modify tour shema later is important.

So yes, I think it's a pretty good pratice (safer than hand applying script under the stress of a production server problem) which cost one or two hours(given you know how to use the tool) and can save dozens when having to handle hotfixing of a production database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will be deploying this application in more than one place - not just production in the cloud, but also development servers, test servers, staging, etc. If that is true, then it seems to me that you definitely want to have a process around how you make changes to the database schema.

For me, over the course of my 20+ years in software development, I have seen several things that I use now that were not in common use when I started but that have now become 'baseline' practices on any project I work on. Yeah, I used to work without source control, but that is an absolute must now. I used to write software without tests, but not any more. I used to work without continuous integration, but that is yet another practice that I consider a must-have. The most recent addition to my must-have list is some sort of automated database migration process.

Also, since Liquibase is built-in to Dropwizard, I don't see any reason ***not*** to use it.